# Upgrading Dev Express 15.1.3 to 16.1.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, boilerplate

I am facing some difficulties upgrading my Asp Mvc Project from version 15.1.3 to 16.1.5.

I am getting the following error.

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

I get this at the login page, and with Inspect Elment I get the error at

`<script src="~/AbpScripts/GetScripts" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating the web config file. It seemed that my connection string to the database was damaged, thus causing the above not working